# Build android apps with Kotlin in termux

Tags: android, kotlin, development-environment

I am currently trying to build an android app but I rarely have access to a pc. Instead I do have an android phone which Is powerful enough and I use termux in it. I just want to know if there is any way I could build an android app in it. Even if it is by installing a Linux distro on it like Ubuntu etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/studio/install - you can download android studio for ubuntu, so would properly work on your phone as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use jvdroid app available in the play store, which can compile kotlin on an android phone.

Here is a link to it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.jvdroid